# How to get daily concurrent user in google analytic?

Tags: google-analytics, google-api

I want to know what was the real time data in peak time. Is there any way then please let me know?

Comment: I dint get what u mean?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

To see your peeks you could split your report with a second dimension on a minute basis.
In the GA-Interface go to BEHAVIOR >> Site Content >> Landing Page >> Second Dimension = "Minute index".

In the GA-API you could use = `ga:dateHourMinute`

Comment: its only showing 2000 real time traffic for 1 day. however my real time traffic for yesterday was 16000